# If matrix $A$ in $\mathbb{R}^3 $ such that, $A^3 = I$, $\det A = 1$. Is there a such matrix which is not orthogonal, rotation and identity?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, orthogonality

I tried to use Cayley–Hamilton theorem to learn something about the matrix.
Using the theorem we have:

$p(A)=0 = - A^3 + \text{tr} A\cdot A^2 -\left(\begin{vmatrix}a_{11} && a_{12} \\ a_{21} && a_{22} \end{vmatrix} + \begin{vmatrix}a_{22} && a_{23} \\ a_{32} && a_{33} \end{vmatrix} + \begin{vmatrix}a_{11} && a_{13} \\ a_{31} && a_{33} \end{vmatrix}\right) A + \det A$.
Since $-A^3 + \det A \cdot I = 0$, then $A = \frac{\left(\begin{vmatrix}a_{11} && a_{12} \\ a_{21} && a_{22} \end{vmatrix} + \begin{vmatrix}a_{22} && a_{23} \\ a_{32} && a_{33} \end{vmatrix} + \begin{vmatrix}a_{11} && a_{13} \\ a_{31} && a_{33} \end{vmatrix}\right)}{\text{tr} A}I$. With this in mind I cannot obtain even rotation matrix to say nothing about something else. Any hints?

Comment: Is $E$ what we commonly denote as $I$ (the identity matrix)?

Comment: Yes it is. I've corrected my question.

Comment: Is it assumed that $\deg A = 3$?

Comment: Yes. I start with consideration of rotation matrix  through $\frac{2\pi}{3}$ angle about any axis, but as far as understood, there is such matrices with this property, which is not rotation matrix.

Comment: Well, a rotation must have eigen-value 1. So how about a diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are in $\{e^{2\pi i/3}, e^{4\pi i/3}\}$?

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan, these are good one, it solution of last the equality. My main question, however, is there non-orthogonal matrices? And why Cayley-Hamilton theorem doesn't show rotation matrices?

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan, from the last equality we can conclude, that $a_{11}(a_{22} - 1^{1/3}) + a_{22}(a_{33} - 1^{1/3}) + a_{33}(a_{11} - 1^{1/3}) = 0$. It is clear, that your suggestion is valid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a quick example: 
$$
A = \pmatrix{\cos(2\pi/3) & -10\sin(2 \pi /3) & 0\\
\frac 1{10}\sin(2 \pi /3) & \cos (2 \pi /3) & 0\\0 & 0 & 1}
$$
Is like the usual rotation, but with the off-diagonal entries slightly altered.  Show that $A^3 = I$, but $A$ is **not** orthogonal (or a rotation) since $A^TA \neq I$.

---

Another easy example:
$$
A = \pmatrix{\cos(2\pi/3) & \sin(2 \pi /3) & 2\\
\sin(2 \pi /3) & \cos (2 \pi /3) & 3\\0 & 0 & 1}
$$
the same argument applies.

Comment: Very nice example! Do you know how to argue that Cayley–Hamilton implies $A$ diagonal? This would complete the answer nicely.

Comment: @JJR you mean that $A$ is **diagonalizable**.  Here's a proof that works in the $n \times n$ case: since $A^3 - I = 0$, we know that the minimal polynomial of $A$ divides $x^3 - 1$.  This means that the minimal polynomial of $A$ is the product of distinct linear factors, which means that $A$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: @JJR in the $3 \times 3$ case, there's an easier argument: since $A^3 = I$, the eigenvalues satisfy $\lambda^3 = 1$.  Since eigenvalues come in conjugate pairs, it suffices to address the cases a) where $A$ has all $3$ eigenvalues and b) where $A$ has $1$ as its only eigenvalue.  In the first case, $A^3 = I$ by Cayley Hamilton.  In the second case, either $A = I$ or $A$ fails to satisfy A^3 = I.  Note in particular that $A^3 - I = (A - I)(A^2 + A + I)$, and that the second matrix in the product is invertible when $1$ is the only eigenvalue.

Comment: @JJR I didn't see anything in his question about " arguing that Cayley–Hamilton implies A diagonal", by the way.

Comment: @ Omnomnomnom Thanks again for nice comments. Btw. I was refering to the part where he shows $A=c\cdot I$ and argues to not even obtain a rotation matrix.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, I don't understand it too. Why Cayley-Hamilton theorem implies that due to this condition $A=cI$? I use this theorem in some wrong way? Where is my fault? By the way, I used your example and obtained that $\text{tr}A\cdot A^2\neq (…)A$. PS. I take this opportunity to say thanks for your nice example and comments.

Comment: @IR55 I don't think I understand your question.  You're asking why "Cayley-Hamilton theorem implies that due to **this condition** $A=cI$"; which condition are you talking about?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, I meant given conditions: $A^3 = I, \det A = 1$. Please, look at the second part of my question above again. When using C-H theorem, we obtain: $-A^3 + \det A \cdot I = 0, \text{tr} A \cdot A^2 - (\dots) \cdot A = 0$, from which we should conclude that $A = cI$, where $c = \frac{(\dots)}{\text{tr}A}$, or we shouldn't conclude that? Why? If we should, then matrix should be diagonal, how we obtain rotation matrix? Is diagonal matrix with complex coefficients equivalent to some rotation matrix with reals?

Comment: Aha.  We shouldn't conclude that. One cannot simply take the "cube root" of a matrix.

Comment: I tried to learn something about the matrix by means of C.-H. theorem. Why C.-H. doesn't holds here? With the usage of your example we can show that $-A^3 + \det A \cdot I = 0$, but $\text{tr} A\cdot A^2 - (\dots) \cdot A \neq  0$. It's still unclear for me.

Comment: We have $A^3 = c^3I$ (for some scalar $c$).  It **does not follow** that $A = cI$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $A^3-I=0$ you get that the possible eigenvalues are $1, e^{2\pi i/3}, e^{4\pi i/3}$.

Moreover, since $A$ is $3 \times 3$ it has 1 or 3 real eigenvalues.

**Case 1:** All eigenvalues are real. Then, the minimal polynomial of $A$ is $(x-1)^k$ and divides $x^3-1$, therefore it is $x-1$. This shows that $A$ is diagonalizable and hence
$$A=PIP^{-1}=I$$.

**Case 2:** $A$ has two complex eigenvalues.  Then, $1, e^{2\pi i/3}, e^{4\pi i/3}$ are all eigenvalues, with eigenvectors $u,v, \bar{v}$.

You have $A=PDP^{-1}$ where 
$$P=(u v \bar{V})$$ and $D=diag (1, e^{2\pi i/3}, e^{4\pi i/3})$

Now, write $$v=v_1+i v_2$$ Show that 
$$A= (u \;v_2 \;v_2) \begin{bmatrix}1 &0 & 0\\
0& \cos(2\pi /3 )& \sin(2\pi /3)\\
0& -\sin(2\pi /3 )& \cos(2\pi /3)
\end{bmatrix}(u \;v_2 \;v_2) ^{-1}$$